# Cannot read property 'context' of undefined - Sitecore 9

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to build a baisc application on **Sitecore 9.0 Update -1** - JSS. This is a vanilla installation.

I installed Sample JSS file and ran the following command.

```
jss deploy package --includeContent --includeDictionary
```

Command got executed successfully. Even I am able to see all the component inside the Sitecore CMS but when I tried to browse the page after publishing it is showing below error:

> Cannot read property 'context' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'context' of undefined    at
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore9.sc\dist\cricket\server.bundle.js:1:56404 
>   at     at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)

[image]

Please can somebody tell me how can I fixed this.

Thanks in advance